# inclined slope question

Tags: classical-mechanics

On an inclined slope, when an object is being pulled up by a string, the vertical force is of the string is downwards. Why is that, when the object is being pulled up?

Comment: It's not: The force of the string on the object is upwards. However, the reaction force of the object on the string must therefore be downwards.

Comment: In fact, if the angle of inclination is $\theta$, and $g$ represents the force of gravity, $m$ represents the mass being pulled, and friction is assumed to be $0$,
then the upwards force is $mg\sin(\theta).$

Comment: This implies that in the mythical world where friction is $0$, if the angle of inclination is $(\theta = 0)$, then a tiny push of the object (similar to a pool ball on a frictionless pool table) will cause the object to go *forever*.

Comment: @Semiclassical are the force and the reaction force the same magnitude but opposite direction?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The string is **in tension**, indicating that **equal and opposite** forces apply to it.  Weight of the object (due to gravity) pulls down on the bottom of the string, while the force applied by the puller pulls upwards on the top of the string.  This should clarify any ambiguity you have in relation to whether forces pull up versus down.

The diagonal force of the string can be decomposed into a horizontal and vertical component.

The directly downwards force of gravity and the diagonal force up directly out of the surface combine to precisely the equal magnitude and opposite direction to the force on the string.